Does Pointwise Tightness of a sequence of stochastic processes imply Aldous' Criterion?
Billingsley's Convergence of Probability Measures provides the following two criteria by Aldous:

$\forall m\in \mathbb N: \lim_{a\to\infty}\lim\sup_{n\in\mathbb N} \mathbb P(\sup_{t\leq m}|X^n_t|>a)=0$.
A stopping time criterion.

Together they imply tightness of the sequence $(\mathbb P^{X^n})_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset \mathcal P(C([0,T]; \mathbb R^d))$.
I have shown, in lieu of 1.), that for every $t\in[0,T], (\mathbb P^{X^n_t})_{n\in\mathbb N} \subset \mathcal P(\mathbb R^d)$ is tight. I would like to show that this pointwise tightness implies criterion 1.).
First of all, pointwise tightness implies: $\forall t\in[0,T] \exists \epsilon_t: \exists M_{\epsilon_t}: \forall n\in\mathbb N: \mathbb P(|X^n_t|>M_{\epsilon_t}) < \epsilon_t$. To obtain 1.), we can ignore the quantifications over $m$ and $n$, as $m$ is obtained once we have the assertion for $[0,T]$, and the tightness criterion holds uniformly in $n$.
Now, these are my two approaches to transfer the given bound of the probability to a bound on the supremum over time:
A.) Set $a:=\sup_{t\in[0,T]} M_{\epsilon_t}, \epsilon_a:= \inf_{t\in[0,T]}\epsilon_t$. I am not sure if the given tightness criteria then simply already imply $\mathbb P(\sup_{t\in[0,T]}|X_t|>a)<\epsilon_a$ ? I don't know if this is rigorous?
B.) The idea is to use Boole's inequality to obtain something of the sort $\mathbb P(\sup_{t\in[0,T]} |X_t|>a) \leq \sum_{t\in[0,T]} \mathbb P (|X_t|>a)$. However, this sum is uncountable. To obtain something countable using the tightness criterion my ansatz is $A_t:=\{s\in[0,T]|\mathbb P(|X_s|>M_{\epsilon_t})<\epsilon_t\}$. The $A_t, t\in[0,T]$ are an open cover of $[0,T]$, so Heine-Borel yields a finite subcover $A_{t_i}, i\leq N$. I should then be able to bound the supremum over the entire interval with the supremums over the $A_{t_i}$:
$\mathbb P(\sup_{t\in[0,T]}|X_t|>M_N) \leq \sum_{i=1}^N\mathbb P (\sup_{t\in A_{t_i}}|X_t|>M_{\epsilon_{t_i}})<\sum_{i=1}^N\epsilon_{t_i},$
with $M_N:=\max M_{\epsilon_{t_i}}$. Then, with $a:=M_N$ and $\epsilon_a:=\sum_{i=1}^N\epsilon_{t_i}$ one should intuitively get $\epsilon_a\to0$ as $a\to\infty$, but I am unsure how to show this - in particular one needs to find a smaller finite subcover for larger $a$, in particular with a smaller $\epsilon_a$. I struggle to construct a function from $a$ to the finite subcover, though.

For reference, as it may influence the applicability of A.): My Processes are all a.s. continuous.

I have found the original paper by Aldous', which actually gives tightness for every $t$ as the first criterion. The relationship between the two options is still unclear to me, however as Billingsley, Convergence of Measures, cites the supremum based criterion 1 I gave above, this likely implies the tightness at every $t$. I am content with just working with tightness at every $t$, though.
